# CSS: How to create a background cutout using elements (not images)?

Tags: css, z-index

I am trying to create a sort of "window" effect where the div positioned above all the other elements is like a window through the overlay (background color) element positioned exactly below it.

[Here is an example of what I mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/VRLNJ/1/)

I would like the text to show through as if you were looking through a window. How can this be done without the use of images?

### Solution:

One solution is to create a very wide semi-transparent border. However, that approach affects the overall dimensions (or appearance of dimensions).

An alternative solution (the one that I am using) is to set a semi-transparent [box-shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)
with a large spread, eliminating the need for a separate overlay div.

```
#cutout {
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 0px 5000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 0px 5000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: Here's the complete working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRLNJ/193/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per i understand may be that's you want

### http://jsfiddle.net/VRLNJ/2/

Comment: hmm...that's a very interesting solution to the problem. Unfortunately that won't work for me unless you can set the border to display on the outside, since it affects the appearance of the dimensions of the "window div"

Comment: you gave me the idea for a different solution, so I'm giving you the credit

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/VRLNJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

I came with the same idea recently for my project and this so called cut out doesn't work.The transparent window is still a layer above and if you can see and scroll you can't 'Touch' the layer bellow for example if you have <a herf="> underneath.
I would happy if someone show  a real cut out. Something like select the area and delete it so only frame will left.