# Cut out of css image container

Tags: html, css, position

Hi, I am trying to position two images next to each other and have one of them overlap the other one in a corner.

I have tried using the `z-index` property but this does not work unless i set the position property to something like fixed or absolute and this messes up the layout of my site.

I was wondering that although i have an image container with the width and height set, can i possibly cut out a section of the container like a rectangle to let the image sit inside the cut like the image below me.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This could help you out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890179/css-how-to-create-a-background-cutout-using-elements-not-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position:relative positions the element relative to its normal position, and pretends, for document flow, that the element is still there. See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GtJMF/

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how having a `position:absolute` for this scenario would mess up your site.

Put `position:relative` on your "Image Container". Put `position:absolute; right:0, bottom:0;` on your "Cut out part" (assuming it is also in the Image Container). This will give you the exact effect you are looking for.

Positioning is relative to the containing positioned parent. Just a `position:relative` is enough make an element a "positioning master" that all interior positioning will use for its coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

`position:relative` also "enables" `z-index`, but unlike `absolute` and `fixed` it doesn't mess up any of the rest of the layout.